# Stuck in inductive step

Tags: induction

## Statement

Use mathematical induction to show that given a set of
n + 1 positive integers, none exceeding 2n, there is at
least one integer in this set that divides another integer in
the set.

It's clear that the set can't contain two equal integers because one divides the other.

## Basis step:

When n=1 the set S has two positive integers, namely S = {1,2}, and 1 divides 2.

## Inductive step

Let's assume that when a set S has K+1 positive integers and each one is not greater than 2K, there is at least one integer in this set that divides another integer in the set.

Now I'm stuck, I don't know how to show that assuming this hypothesis I can prove that the statement holds for (K+1)+1.

Comment: In general your question will be better received if you show some effort beyond simply stating the problem. For example, what have you tried? Is there somewhere specific that you are stuck at? You might say something like "I know induction is..., but I can't seem to prove ..." or "I tried doing it for n=..."

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for that.

Comment: So I notice that in the $K+1$ step you essentially either have the pair that fulfills the requirement or you must include $2K+1$ and $2K+2$ perhaps there is something in that direction?

Comment: Well, I really look at the notebook, but I can't see anything.

Answer (score -1):

##I'm bad at English, sentences may be wrong in grammar.

Let $P(n)$ be any subset $S$ containing $n+1$ distinct positive integers no exceeding $2n$ must have at least one pair of integers in which one can divide the other or vise versa.

**Basis Step**: $P(1)$ is true,because $S = \{1,2\}$ and $1 | 2$.

**Inductive Step**: When $P(k)$ is true, $P(k+1)$ states that set $S$ of $k+2$ elements must contain no less than one pair. There are $3$ cases below:

A: No element of $S$ is in $Y=\{2k+1, 2k+2\}$. So $k+2$ elements are no bigger than $2k$. $P(k)$ makes it true.

B: Only one element is in $Y$. $P(k)$ makes it true as well.

C: Two elements are in $Y$. Let $X = S - Y$, which contains $k$ elements no exceeding $2k$. $2k+1$ may be prime, so we don't care about it.
Assuming the contradiction, no pairs are found in $S$. With $2k+2$ in $S$, if $k+1$ in $S$, $P(k+1)$ is true. If $k+1$ is not in $S$, obviously all factors of $2k+2$ within $2k$ are also factors of $k+1$.Then we can swap $2k+2$ in $S$ with $k+1$ to form $S'$ and don't change the number of pairs in $S$. Case B makes $S'$ contains at least one pair, So does $S$. As a result, the contradiction is false.